# Moving folders on SVN

Tags: windows-7, tortoisesvn

I want to move all contents in **server directory**
from

```
https://myweb.com:8443/svn/Papers/MyName/MySoftware
```

to

```
https://myweb.com:8443/svn/NewDir/MyName/MySoftware
```

from the **client site tortoise SVN**,

so that I could subsequently checkout from

```
https://myweb.com:8443/svn/NewDir/MyName/MySoftware
```

how should I achieve that?

I have seen there is a relocate and switching command in the Windows context menu,
but I am not sure are there doing the thing I wish to achieved.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN will checkout and will create output of SVN server. If you want to keep SVN stuff, formatting, versioning, users, you have to zip entire Repository folder of your SVN server, then reload it in another SVN server. If you checkout from SVN server, you cannot re-run an SVN server with same versioning, users, etc. from a checkout version

Comment: Can I achieve this using the client of tortoise svn?

Comment: No, I think your server is VisualSVN server, just open httpd.conf in VisualSVN server, find repositories, zip that folder, now you can re-run SVN server in another location. Without server, you cannot do it from TortoiseSVN client output. You should do from server, not client.

Answer (score 0):

**If** my reconstruction

> `Papers` and `NewDir` are repositories (because URLs patterns remind me server with SVNParentPath inside `svn` location), and you want to save old tree-structure, but have it in another repositories

is correct **and pre-condition** "Repository NewDir already exist and you have permissions to commit into it" is fulfilled:

You can *try* to do it from client-side. Relocate you WC (root) from `https://myweb.com:8443/svn/Papers/MyName/MySoftware` to `https://myweb.com:8443/svn/NewDir/MyName/MySoftware` and commit. In case of error like "Repository unrelated, UUID mismatch" - checkout new (empty?)repo, copy your old WC (withoot .svn directory) to new WC, add, commit